# How can I spot remove a stain from my white garment?

Tags: clothing

I often drop Coffee on my white garment. Normally I wash after 10 or so wears, but this makes me want to wash it sooner.

Is there anyway to spot remove stains effectively and cheaply?

Most ideas provided online doesn't seem to help much

Answer (score 0):

**How can I spot remove a stain from my white garment?**

Try using [**Shout**](https://www.shoutitout.com/en-us/products/triple-acting) on your stain before washing it.

[image]

I have used this many times on white fabrics including blood and it works great.

Follow the directions and let it soak in for at least 20 minutes before washing in cold water.

Answer (score 0):

**Materials you'll need:**

- Cold water
- Liquid laundry detergent or dish soap
- White vinegar
- Baking soda (optional)
- Clean, white cloth or paper towels

**Step-by-step process:**

1. **Blot the stain**: Gently blot the stain with a clean, white cloth or paper towel. Do not rub, as it can spread the stain.
2. **Rinse with cold water**: Hold the fabric under the tap and run cold water through the back of the stain. This helps to flush out as much of the coffee as possible.
3. **Pre-treat with detergent or dish soap:**

- Apply a small amount of liquid laundry detergent or dish soap directly to the stain.
- Gently rub the fabric together to work the soap into the stain.
- Fill a basin or sink with cold water and soak the garment for at least 15-30 minutes.

4. **Check the stain:** After soaking, check the stain's progress. If it's still visible, you can try the next steps.
5. **Try white vinegar:**

- Mix equal parts of white vinegar and cold water.
- Use a sponge or cloth to apply the solution to the stain.
- Blot with a clean cloth and rinse with cold water.

6. ***Use baking soda (optional):***

- Make a paste by mixing baking soda with water.
- Put the paste on the stain and let it sit for 15-30 minutes.
- Rinse thoroughly with cold water.

7. **Check the stain again:** See if the stain is still visible after following these steps. If it is, you may want to repeat the process or consider professional dry cleaning.
8. **Wash the garment**: Wash the garment as usual once you've successfully removed the coffee stain. Follow the care instructions on the garment's label.